# NULL Integer in multi-column in clause

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run a multi-column in clause that matches null values as well. Right now I'm using coalesce like so:

```
select * from table 
where (coalesce(foo, ''), coalesce(bar, '')) in (('foo_val', 'bar_val'), ('foo_val', ''));
```

For integer columns though, this throws 'invalid input syntax for integer: ""' on the coalesce. I could coalesce to -1 instead of an empty string, but was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Sample input/output:
Table data: 
{{foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 1, bar: NULL}}
User input: [(1, 2), (1, nil)]
Expected output: both rows.

EDIT: I'll try to clarify what I'm trying to do: I want to match DB rows by multiple column value combinations given by the user. That is, if the user inputs [(1,2), (3,4)], I'd want to return rows where column_A == 1 AND column_B == 2, OR column_A == 3 AND column_B == 4. Where I run into trouble is allowing for the user to input NULL and have it matched like any other value. So if the user inputs [(1,NULL)], I'd want to return rows where column_A == 1 AND column_B == NULL (but note I wouldn't want to return them for the previous query, since the user didn't specify he wanted rows with NULL values in column_B).

Comment: Can you give sample input and expected output ?

Comment: `select * from tbr
where (coalesce(var, ''::text), coalesce(var1, ''::text)) in (('foo_val', 'bar_val'), ('foo_val', ''));` ? Are yiu trying to achieve something like this - http://hastebin.com/ayonudazew.sql ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will not just match nulls, it will also match empty strings. If that's what you want, then fine.

Using a hard-coded list in an IN clause, where you wish to also return nulls, the simplest solution is to coalesce against the first value in your IN list. That way you don't have to worry about matching non-null values (like empty strings or -1) which aren't in the list.

```
select * 
from table 
where (coalesce(foo, 'foo_val'), coalesce(bar, 'foo_val')) 
in (('foo_val', 'bar_val'), ('foo_val', ''));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to return all nulls, but to match nulls in the user input. Also, in your example, the row {foo: 'foo_val', bar: NULL} wouldn't be retrieved, since it'd be matched as {foo: 'foo_val', bar: 'foo_val'}.

Comment: I am afraid I can't help any further because I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Added clarification, hope it helps